# I got error message 'not finished load plugins'

Tags: npm

I got error message 'not finished load plugins', when I trying to load local server with [npm run develop]

What should I do?

This is the error message I got:

```
not finished load plugins - 0.975s
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Henisis@0.2.0 develop: `GATSBY_ENV=staging gatsby develop`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the Henisis@0.2.0 develop script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mingyeongso/.npm/_logs/2020-04-08T06_51_49_655Z-debug.log
mingyeongui-MacBookPro:henesis-website mingyeongso$
```

From the debug file:

0 info it worked if it ends with ok

1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'develop' ]

2 info using npm@6.14.2

3 info using node@v10.16.3

4 verbose run-script [ 'predevelop', 'develop', 'postdevelop' ]

5 info lifecycle Henisis@0.2.0~predevelop: Henisis@0.2.0

6 info lifecycle Henisis@0.2.0~develop: Henisis@0.2.0

7 verbose lifecycle Henisis@0.2.0~develop: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true

8 verbose lifecycle Henisis@0.2.0~develop: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/mingyeongso/Documents/GitHub/henesis-website/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

9 verbose lifecycle Henisis@0.2.0~develop: CWD: /Users/mingyeongso/Documents/GitHub/henesis-website

10 silly lifecycle Henisis@0.2.0~develop: Args: [ '-c', 'GATSBY_ENV=staging gatsby develop' ]

11 silly lifecycle Henisis@0.2.0~develop: Returned: code: 1 signal: null

12 info lifecycle Henisis@0.2.0~develop: Failed to exec develop script

13 verbose stack Error: Henisis@0.2.0 develop: `GATSBY_ENV=staging gatsby develop`

13 verbose stack Exit status 1

13 verbose stack at EventEmitter. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)

13 verbose stack at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)

13 verbose stack at ChildProcess. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)

13 verbose stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)

13 verbose stack at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)

13 verbose stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)

14 verbose pkgid Henisis@0.2.0

15 verbose cwd /Users/mingyeongso/Documents/GitHub/henesis-website

16 verbose Darwin 18.7.0

17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "develop"

18 verbose node v10.16.3

19 verbose npm v6.14.2

20 error code ELIFECYCLE

21 error errno 1

22 error Henisis@0.2.0 develop: `GATSBY_ENV=staging gatsby develop`

22 error Exit status 1

23 error Failed at the Henisis@0.2.0 develop script.

23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this error by this:

```
npm cache clean --force
delete package-lock.json file
npm install
```